# Sign In Logs With No Client App

Tags: logging, azure, entra-id, denial-of-service

We've been having some issues with our Office 365 services, specifically Exchange online. Some of our users are getting attacked from various countries in attempts to get into their accounts. We're pretty good from a security perspective (I think..) and have the following mitigations in place:

- We user Pass Through Authentication (PTA)
- We have complex Passwords in place
- We use account lockout to stop brute force attacks
- Users are protected with MFA
- We use conditional access to disable legacy authentication

I know all the above are working because I can see, for example, that things like POP3 are being blocked by Conditional Access Policy. However we are still experiencing account lockouts and I can't establish the specific app/service that is the cause. My usual port of call is the Azure AD Sign-In logs. The screen-grab below shows the logs filtered to a single user and the failed logins. Normally, the '**Client App**' field gives you an indication of what service the sign-in was attached to, but its blank (highlighted red in screenshot below). This is happening for multiple users in my tenant and because we can't see/understand the cause, we can't troubleshoot. In a weird way, its becoming a basic DoS issue as users are being locked out and we can't understand how. Microsoft recommends turning on conditional access and blocking legacy authentication, but we've done this already and seem to be still having issues. Do others have this issue and does anyone have any advice?

[See Screen Shot of Logs Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgd4m.jpg)

### Update:

Disabing POP3, IMAP and SMTP on each mailbox seems to be helping. I used the following script to do this in bulk as we have quite a large tenant:

**Just be aware of the consequences if you use this powershell script as you might disable features on accounts that legitimately use POP 3, IMAP and SMTP. This script does it for all mailboxes!!!**

```
$mailboxes = get-casmailbox
foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes){Set-CASMailbox $mailbox.id -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $true -ImapEnabled $false -PopEnabled $False}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew-Emmett You never really seem to ask a question related to you post title but what I would suggest you do if you can is to pull the data from the Office 365 Management API. You will need to register an app in AAD to do this but it will allow you to retain the data for longer than it gets retained by Office 365 and you can develop heuristics from the collected data. You can do it with PowerShell and you can store it in a myriad of forms but one useful one might be to put it into SQL.

If you have the flexibility, you can use an Azure Function App to pull the data. This will also provide you a way to register the Function App as a Webhook on each of the 5 feeds that are part of the API so that when new data hits a feed, the Function App gets notified to go pull the data. You could also do something similar with a Logic App.